# Difficulty accessing database on 000webhost

Tags: mysql, node.js, web-services

I'm facing a problem to access the database using node.js, in local development it works perfectly however, when I go to verify in the cloud it doesn't work, I already changed the database information and they are correct, they work with php request, but not as node. my code is like this currently.

```
index.js file
import express from "express";
import userRoutes from "./routes/userAgent.js"
import cors from "cors";

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use("/", userRoutes)

app.listen(8800);

db.js file
import mysql from "mysql";

export const db = mysql.createConnection({
 host: "",
 user: "",
 password: "",
 database: "",});

db.connect((error)=>{
 if(error) throw error;
 console.log(`Connected to database`)});`
```

I removed the bank information, for security reasons but it is definitely correct, can someone help me solve this problem

There is no browser console this message: localhost:8800/:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I expected to be able to make this connection with node.js but I couldn't